# Stripe connect, express account wrong business name in receipt

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I created an app with stripe express account. Everything is working well except that the name on the receipt is my platform name instead of the connected account name
.
My plat form has businesses. Each business has their customer.
When the customer of each business pays for their services, my platform should send the receipt in the business name not my name. I am using destination charges:

```
try{
            $charge=$stripe->charges->create([
                "customer"=>$this->stripeCustID,
                "amount" => $amount,
                "currency" => "cad",                    
                "description" => $this->input->post('product'),
                "statement_descriptor" => mb_strimwidth($company->full_name, 0, 22, ''),
                 'receipt_email' => $customerEmail,
                 'application_fee_amount' => $fee,       
                 
                  'on_behalf_of' => $destinationAcct,
                  'transfer_data' => [
                    'destination' => $destinationAcct,
                  ],
        ]);
```

What do I need to change? What am I doing wrong. I called stripe and most of them tech team have no idea how to fix this

Comment: What is the value of `statement_descriptor` coming from (the platform, or the connected account name)? That defines what shows up on the customer's bank statement.

Comment: The value in the statement descriptor is the business(connected) account name which is correct. The issue is that the receipt that is sent to the customer of the connected account bears my platform's name. This is the problem. I want it to show the information on the statement descriptor.Any ideas

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to the [Stripe Support Team](https://support.stripe.com/email) as there are definitely some issues with statement descriptors when dealing with Connect, and they'll be able to provide you with an exact answer based on looking at your account's logs.

Comment: Stripe team said its not possible. This is not good. Why did they have connected account that is poorly designed with smear support?